Susskind GR: expansion of one set of coordinates in terms of another coordinate set
In lecture 3 of Leonard Susskind's Theoretical Minimum course on general relativity, he shows the expansion of one set of coordinates, $x^m$, in terms of another set, $y^m$, as
$$
\begin{equation}
  x^m = y^m + C^m_{n r} y^n y^r.
\end{equation}
$$
He considers the point of expansion to be the coordinate system origin, which is the origin in both coordinate systems.
Where does this come from?
If I perform a Taylor series expansion of $x^m(y^0, y^1, y^2, y^3)$ I get something different:
$$
\begin{align}
  x^m &= (x^m)_p + \left(\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial y^n}\right)_p y^n
  + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial^2 x^m}{\partial y^n \partial y^r}\right)_p y^n y^r
  + \ldots,\\
  &= 0 + \left(\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial y^n}\right)_p y^n
  + C^m_{n r} y^n y^r + \ldots,\\
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
\begin{equation}
  C^m_{n r} \equiv
    \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial^2 x^m}{\partial y^n \partial y^r}\right)_p.
\end{equation}
$$
In order for my expansion to match his,
$$
\begin{equation}
  \left(\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial y^n}\right)_p y^n = y^m,
\end{equation}
$$
which is true if
$$
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
  \left(\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial y^n}\right)_p = \delta^m_n.
\end{equation}
$$
Is there any justification for saying eqn (1) is true? If I'm not mistaken, this is only true if $x$ describes the same coordinate system as $y$, which sort of defeats the point of the expansion.
He presents the same expansion in the accompanying book on page 93.
